# Can I prefix with $ (dollar sign) my URL query string parameters safely?

Tags: rest, url

I am starting to implement filtering through query strings in my API REST application where I can perform filtering on any field passed to a entity in my database. But there are especial parameters that I want to differentiate like; `sort`, `page`, `direction`, etc from the rest of fields that will be used to filter the collection.

I want to avoid using an implementation like:

`/?filters=field1:value1,field2:value2&page=3&per_page=50`

Because I will need to make a custom parser to the `filters` value.

My desired structure is something more plain, like this:

`/?lastname=Halden&country=somewhere&$sort=lastname`

So, all the properties that aren't prefixed with **`$`** are used to make the filter and the other properties with the prefix are used to tweak the result.

My actual question is that if **it is safe**?. If there can exist a problem in the moment to parse the whole query string in some libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be ok. As a matter of fact, [ODATA](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/), one of the widely used REST standards in enterprise software uses `$` the same way you want to use. Another sensible option you could use is `_` (e.g. `_sort`, `_page`, etc.)